# Advantages of Gitlab Infrastructure registry for terraform modules

Tags: gitlab, terraform

I'm having a hard time to understand the advantage(s) of Gitlab Infrastructure Registry to publish terraform modules as opposite to just referencing the git repo. Difference in usage

**Referencing the repo:**

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
before_script:
  - git config --global url."https://oauth2:${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com"
```

terraform:

```
module "module_test" {
  source = "git::https://gitlab.com/terraform-modules/local_file?ref=v0.1.0"
}
```

**Using the infrastructure registry**

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  TF_CLI_CONFIG_FILE: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.terraformrc

before_script:
  - echo -e "credentials \"$CI_SERVER_HOST\" {\n  token = \"$CI_JOB_TOKEN\"\n}" > $TF_CLI_CONFIG_FILE
```

terraform:

```
module "my_module_name" {
  source = "gitlab.com/terraform-modules/local_file/local"
  version = "0.1.0"
}
```

so why bother to create modules in the infrastructure registry ? what am I missing ?

Comment: The version argument supports more robust values than the git ref. Otherwise, not much from the perspective of the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

- A module registry is the native way of distributing Terraform modules for use across multiple configurations, using a **Terraform-specific protocol** that has full support for module versioning [Gitlab follows Terraform’s Module Registry Protocol](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/internals/module-registry-protocol)
- Registry modules support **versioning**. You can provide a specific version as shown in the above examples, or use flexible version constraints.You can use of the version, e.g. in your versions.tf

  [image]
- You can have **multiple modules in one** Terraform module **registry**
- With the Registry, you can specify **dependencies** between modules. This ensures that changes to one module trigger appropriate updates in dependent modules, reducing the risk of configuration drift.
- **Service Discovery**. Various operations that a module registry must implement.

  - List Available Versions for a specific module
  - Download Source Code for a Specific Module Version